# QImage and openmp when updating image display

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, openmp, qimage

In Qt 5.5 for mac, I am trying to speed up the computation the image buffer and its display with QImage. I was using openMP directives but I realised this was messing with the QImage display.

Here is the code:

```
int = 65535    
newPaintImage = new QImage(naxis1, naxis2, QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
#pragma omp parallel for
for ( int ii = 0; ii < nPixels; ++ii )
{
    cred = (int) 255 * red16[ii] / range;
    cgreen = (int) 255 * green16[ii] / range;
    cblue = (int) 255 * blue16[ii] / range;     

    QRgb argb = qRgba( cred, cgreen, cblue, 255);
    QRgb* rowData = (QRgb*) newPaintImage->scanLine(ii/naxis1);
    rowData[ii%naxis1] = argb;
}
newPaintWidget = new PaintWidget(newPaintImage, naxis1, naxis2);
```

In the code above, `nPixels` is the total number of pixels in the image and `red16`, `green16`, and `blue16` are the 3 color channel of my images. They have a size equal to `nPixels`. The values `naxis1` and `naxis2` are the width and height (in pixels).

Note the pragma directive to parallelise the for loop. When I use it, I get scrambled lines in my image, and any update to the image is changing the results.
When I do not use the pragma directive, so that only one thread is used, my image is fine, as expected. 
I change and update the buffer with such parallelisation, and that mess with the display.

Is there a better way? Like making sure that my threads finished the job and then update the display in my Qt object's paintEvent? Or something related to how the QImage is shared across the threads?...

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `private(cred, cgreen, cblue)` to your OpenMP pragma. Not sure it will suffice, but it is definitely needed.

Comment: The more I read this, the more I feel confident that `#pragma omp parallel for private(cred, cgreen, cblue)`should just be enough for your code to work in parallel. Not sure it will be any faster though, since your code is mostly memory bound.

Comment: @gilles
Ok, i just tried it with `#pragma omp parallel for private(cred, cgreen, cblue)`, and i got a compilation error: 
`error: expected variable name
#pragma omp parallel for private(cred, cgreen, cblue)`
i'm totally ignorant with these directives. Any idea?

Comment: @gilles Got it working! The cred, cgreen, cblue were private to the class. So the directive needed this:
`int cred2, cgreen2, cblue2;
#pragma omp parallel for private(cred2, cgreen2, cblue2)`
I'm posting the corrected code. Thanks for your help! That was quick!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion in the comment, I fixed it. The pragma clause `private` was needed to define private variables to work with.

```
int cred2, cgreen2, cblue2   
#pragma omp parallel for private(cred2, cgreen2, cblue2)
for ( int ii = 0; ii < nPixels; ++ii )
{
    cred2 = (int) 255 * red16[ii] / range;
    cgreen2 = (int) 255 * green16[ii] / range;
    cblue2 = (int) 255 * blue16[ii] / range;
    QRgb argb = qRgba( cred2, cgreen2, cblue2, 255);
    QRgb* rowData = (QRgb*) newPaintImage->scanLine(ii/naxis1);
    rowData[ii%naxis1] = argb;
}
newPaintWidget = new PaintWidget(newPaintImage, naxis1, naxis2);
```

And yes, it is considerably faster! This is used with some QSlider signal/slots, which perform contrast stretching. I simplified the code here. In fact, `range` is changing and not fixed and e.g. `red16[ii]` is `(red16[ii] - minValue)` where `minValue` changes with some QSliders.